# How to recognize object in photo with flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, tensorflow-lite, image-recognition

I have a book with pictures. The task is that a each picture is attached to video, and when the camera hovers over the picture, the application should open another screen and play the video associated with the photo. i tried to use teachablemachine, but it cant detect if there's too many photos. Any ideas is highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: please what you have done and what is the issue with your implementation

Comment: everything works fine with tflite library except one thing. camera image stream sends image to tflite and when tflite processes image camera freezes a little. Isolate doesnt work on platform code. problem now is how to get rid of that delay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Tensoflow Lite: https://www.tensorflow.org/lite
You have some dependencies for flutter, for example: https://pub.dev/packages/tflite

Comment: thanks i found good example of this method and gonna implement it.

Comment: To supress camera delaying i tryed to process tflite in isolate but theres always an error. maybe you already dealt with it and are able to help me. one example would be great.

Answer (score 2):

You could use firebase's [Object Detection and Tracking](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/object-detection) and [Camera Plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/camera)'s image stream feature.

Basically, you would process each frame you get from camera plugin with Firebase's ML feature, and once you detect an object you can perform any action with it.